# docker python official example bugs

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I am learning docker，and I want to make up my python django docker images to run in my mac
I have created 3 files:

1: docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

2: Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

3: Requirements

```
Django>=1.8,<2.0
psycopg2
```

then I run  `sudo docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .` I have created the official example files in my dir

but when I run `docker-compose`

I get an error and it was run failed

```
web_1  | Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fcafcf47510>
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
web_1  |     autoreload.raise_last_exception()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
web_1  |     six.reraise(*_exception)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
web_1  |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
web_1  |     fn(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
web_1  |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
web_1  |     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
web_1  |     module = import_module(entry)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
web_1  |     from django.contrib.admin.filters import (
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/filters.py", line 10, in <module>
web_1  |     from django.contrib.admin.options import IncorrectLookupParameters
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 13, in <module>
web_1  |     from django.contrib.admin import helpers, widgets
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py", line 152
web_1  |     '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
web_1  |     ^
web_1  | SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

Can anybody help me now? I am confused.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still getting that error despite changing my requirements.txt file to:

Django>=2

psycopg2

Any other suggestions? I've pretty much run out of ideas. I've been using https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database. So far as I can tell I've done everything by the book according to that web page.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error was [fixed in django 2.1](https://github.com/django/django/commit/931c60c5216bd71bc11f489e00e063331cf21f40#diff-f42ac10b4a1091330b3ae0c3d0d0a7cf)

You'll want to upgrade your requirements to be `django>=2.1` to ensure you get this new version.

The comments on the commit indicate that this patch will *not* be backported to django 1.11.x which does not support python3.7

> Per [the FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django), Django 1.11.x is not compatible with Python 3.7.
>
> Django 1.11.x reached [end of mainstream support](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions) on December 2, 2017 and it receives only data loss and security fixes until its end of life.

Comment: this answer fixed it for me. I used ==2.1, and before had to ```docker-compose stop```, removed all the generated files in the project dir, and re-ran ```docker-compose build```.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem on my own because of the inconsistency between django version and python3.7。Simply remove the version of django from the requiere.txt file and install the latest one

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer please? I have the same problem, but unclear exactly what you mean by "remove the version of django from the requiere.txt file and install the latest one". What exactly does your requirements.txt file look like now?